# Strange Excel IF formula evaluation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In a particular strange workbook,

In cell A1, I key the value `0`

In cell A2, I key the formula `=IF(A1="APPLE", 1, 0)`

The result in cell A2 gives 1.

I tried to replicate the same in a new workbook, I get 0 in both cells. What happened to the strange workbook? I may seem like I am lying, but it's true. Included below is screen shot but in different cells.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**: Cell A2 (G212) will show 1 when A1 (G211) is 0, empty or case-insensitive Apple e.g. aPpLe, ApPlE etc.

Comment: What happens if you enter "APPLE" or some other value in G211?

Comment: Are you sure that the content of G11 is `"APPLE"`? How is the cell formatted? Could you post a screenshot with the edit focus on G211?

Comment: Cell A2 (G212) will show 1 when A1 (G211) is 0 or case-insensitive Apple e.g. aPpLe, ApPlE etc.

Comment: @Matteo the content of G211 is NOT a formula. It is a `0` manually entered. The desired return value in G212 should be `0`.

Comment: Can you confirm it only happens in this one work book? If so, you know the answer :)  Also, do you not get a Circular Reference Error in G211 (is G211 a formula or did you enter a 0 manually? Also, what happens if you add the word banana into cell G211

Comment: It happens in this workbook and all copies of it. I started a new workbook and cannot get the same behavior. There must be a setting I don't know. G211 is a manual 0, in fact, if i clear G211 (make it empty without any formatting), G212 still show 1.

Comment: What happens when you replace "APPLE" with something else in the formula in G212?

Comment: @Indrek any string, e.g. "any string" will evaluate to true. False otherwise, unless of course you put a number 0.

Comment: Do you have any data validation (select the cell, under Data (in the ribbon) select Data validation - Data validation. Or What If anaylsis/Consoldiation etc

Comment: @DaveRook No data validation or formatting, but i still click on "clear" just for good measures. Problem does not go away.

Comment: Try evaluating the formula step-by-step (Formula tab -> Evaluate Formula), and see if at any point you see an unexpected value in the Evaluation text field. You can also post each of the steps here so we can check them.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you've turned off automatic formula calculation. Under the Formulas tab, either click on "Calculate Now" to force recalculation of all formulae, or click on "Calculation Options" and select "Automatic".

Comment: @Indrek look at screenshots, freaking me out.

Comment: @Indrek it's on Automatic already.

Comment: @DaveRook you can see from third screenshot from the top that editing the formula cell also highlights the G211 cell right above it. So, yea. its the correct worksheet, worksheet B. I mean, if you look at the evaluate formula dialogs, it says `0="APPLE"` is `TRUE`! And yes, G211 when Evaluate, shows just a 0.

Comment: @DaveRook PMT is not the cell name, that box there is a dropdown listing the recently used functions.

Comment: Can you click on G212 and select Formulas, Trace Precedents. Can you confirm an arrow points from G211 to G212 (there is also an option here to remove the arrow)

Comment: What happens if you type in the following formula into a cell? `=(0="APPLE")`. Is the result "TRUE" or "FALSE"?

Comment: @Indrek it shows `1`. Please see screenshot above.

Comment: Thanks all, I got to leave my desk for now while I travell back home. Thank you all for actively following up and helping. Will get back with more updates if I can narrow down the issue some more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. I managed to narrow down the problem to individual worksheet and found the culprit settings.

Go to Excel 2010 Options > Advanced > and then uncheck Transition formula evaluation.

[image]

Comment: Good find! According to [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213953), "if the Transition formula evaluation check box is selected, when Excel evaluates formulas, **text strings are converted to 0**" (emphasis mine). Hence why `0` and "APPLE" were considered equal.